How do I fit a distribution to more than one site at a time in rstan?
There is probably a really easy solution to this, but I’m coming up short. I have code in rstan where I fit a Pareto distribution to data, and I’m looking to find out what the alpha parameter is for the distribution:
data {
    int<lower=0> N;
    real<lower=0> x_min;
    vector<lower=0>[N] x;
}

parameters {
    // Pareto density
    real<lower=0, upper=5> alpha;
}

model {
    // Prior: Pareto density
    alpha ~ lognormal(1, 1) T[0, 5];
    // x_min uniform on its interval.
    
    // Likelihood: Pareto density
    x ~ pareto(x_min, alpha);
}

This works well for a single measured site, where
       N<-length(data$x)
       x<-data$x
       x_min<-x_min
       
       stan_dat<-list(N=N,x=x,x_min=x_min)

However, I have more than one site (so, data$site_label exists). I could just fit a distribution to each site in a for loop in R and get the outputs individually, but is there a way to do all that in just one model? How would I code that?
I've originally used a for loop where I've fit a distribution to each site individually. It works, but I want to try doing it a different way

You can add an array to your Stan data that indexes the site of each observation.  Then alpha will be a vector of parameters (one per site) instead of a single parameter.  Functions like pareto are handily vectorized, so you can still use a single sampling statement that matches each observation with the correct parameter.
Here's what the Stan code might look like.  I assume x_min is the same across all sites; if it's not, that could be changed to a vector too.
data {
  int<lower=0> N;
  real<lower=0> x_min;
  vector<lower=0>[N] x;
  int<lower=0,upper=N> N_sites;
  int<lower=1,upper=N_sites> site[N];
}

parameters {
  // Pareto density
  vector<lower=0, upper=5>[N_sites] alpha;
}

model {
  // Prior: Pareto density
  alpha ~ lognormal(1, 1) T[0, 5];

  // Likelihood: Pareto density
  x ~ pareto(x_min, alpha[site]);
}

And here's some R code demonstrating that the model picks up the correct parameter value for each site.  I've simulated data for five sites.
library(tidyverse)
library(rstan)
library(sads)
theme_set(theme_bw())

# Simulate five sites, each with known alpha
set.seed(24601)
true.values = data.frame(site = 1:5, true.alpha = runif(5, 0, 5))
data = pmap_dfr(
  true.values,
  function(site, true.alpha) {
    data.frame(x = rpareto(100, true.alpha, 1))
  },
  .id = "site"
) %>%
  mutate(site = as.numeric(site))

# Fit a Stan model to the simulated data
stan_dat = list(N = nrow(data),
                x = data$x,
                x_min = 1,
                N_sites = max(data$site),
                site = data$site)
stan_fit = stan("model.stan", data = stan_dat, chains = 3)

# Do the fitted parameters match the true values?  Yes!
rstan::extract(stan_fit, "alpha")$alpha %>%
  data.frame() %>%
  rownames_to_column("n") %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = matches("X"), names_to = "site", names_prefix = "X",
               values_to = "alpha") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = alpha)) +
  geom_histogram() +
  geom_vline(data = true.values %>% mutate(site = as.character(site)),
             aes(xintercept = true.alpha), color = "red") +
  facet_wrap(~ site) +
  labs(x = "Estimated value of alpha", y = "Number of draws")


